# Is it safe to return a casted reference?

Tags: c++, reference, return-type

Let `Point` be a class whose instances can be explicitly casted to a `wxPoint`:

```
class Point{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    explicit operator wxPoint() const
    {
        return wxPoint(x, y);
    }

    // More stuff
}
```

I have a function that returns a reference to an object of type `Point`. The header of such a function is:

```
const Point& GetPoint();
```

My question: is it safe to define the following `Foo` function?

```
const wxPoint& Foo() const{
    return (wxPoint&) GetPoint();
}
```

First I implemented `Foo` with `return (wxPoint) GetPoint();`, but that created a new (local) object and therefore a useful warning is triggered. The code shown here compiles without warnings.

All the information I found on this kind of casting refers to inherited classes, which is not the case here.

An explanation of what is exactly going on when casting a reference in this way would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's perfectly "safe" to define that function. There are ways in which that function could be used that would cause problems and there are ways in which it would not.

Comment: By all means, if you want to write unmaintainable code... (Calling any member function on the returned object will invoke UB though).

Comment: @PeteBecker Why you said it's perfectly "safe"?. In my idea it's perfectly unsafe.

Comment: This is precisely why one should prefer C++ styled cast. If [you had](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f54642308873b0a6), your compiler would have protected you far more rigorously. C style casting to a reference bulldozes over any protection the type system can give you, and you end up returning a possibly dangling references.

Comment: @MRB - I didn't make my point particularly clear. There's no possible harm done by **defining** such a function. There can be harm from **using** it. So whether it's "safe" (whatever that means) depends on its intended use, and there is not enough information in the question to evaluate that.

Comment: It is not safe to return a reference, and not safe to cast a reference to an unrelated type. Return by value from both functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually your conversion operator is never called. You are returning a reference to a `point` instance from `GetPoint`. Later you used a C style cast that in your case will be equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast<>` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)). You are casting a reference to `Point` into a reference to `wxPoint`, and the two are completely unrelated types. On the other hand any operation on the returned reference is undefined behavior.

My suggestion is to always use C++ cast operators. They have benefits:

- C++ style casts are checked by the compiler.
- C++ style casts can be searched easily.
- C++ style casts express the intent of the programmer.

Comment: I suppose that the OP hoped that the conversion operator would be invoked. Would it if the line in question were `return (wxPoint) GetPoint();`, i.e. we'd cast to a proper type? Is that possible at all with a reference?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider that would invoke the conversion operator to construct a `wxPoint` temporary, but would then try to bind a `wxPoint&` to that temporary, which is ill-formed. The problem is the function's return type: you can't return a reference if there's nothing to bind a reference to.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can you say what type of cast is it?

Comment: @MRB - I was going to. But when building the example it unexpectedly worked. So now I need to double check the standard

Comment: Right. It wasn't a problem with the standard, it was GCC being too helpful. Consider [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5670efedbd98f82). The warning from clang is indicative of what's going on. You need to use static_cast to adjust the pointer correctly, but you can't since the base is inaccessible. Only a C-styled cast does the job correctly and with no warning.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK. It's an interesting example. But I think it's again undefined. Compiler try to use `static_cast` and it find it's not possible so it go for `reinterpret_cast`. And as I now casting with multiple inheritance need some pointer adjustment that `reinterpret_cast` doesn't do it.

Comment: I assure you that a C style cast is not doing anything undefined here. It is performing a static_cast but without considering access specifiers. A c style cast will result in the weakest equivalent C++ styled cast (or sequence of casts) that applies.

Comment: See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4). And note the middle paragraph: *"can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, with the exception that in performing a static_­cast in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible"*

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, It do pointer adjustment. Thanks. It was helpful and interesting.

Comment: @StoryTeller Wow. It seemed such an axiom to me that a C style cast is not doing anything else than the C++ casts, in escalating order, until one succeeds.

Comment: Another advantage of C++ casts is that they look ugly. Casts should be ugly, as while they're often useful, they always deserve extra scrutiny.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers have already explained that casting `Point&` to `wxPoint&` simply lies to the compiler, telling it that the object the reference is bound to is a `wxPoint` object, which is not true. Your program will have undefined behaviour if you try to access a `wxPoint` object through that reference, because it isn't bound to a `wxPoint` object. Sometimes when you lie to the compiler it can't give you warnings and just has to trust that you're not doing something crazy.

The fix is to stop trying to return a reference to an object that doesn't exist:

```
wxPoint Foo() const {
    return GetPoint();
}
```

This will use your conversion operator to construct a `wxPoint` and return that by value, which is OK. Trying to return by reference when there is nothing to bind the reference to is not OK.

Comment: Sadly, I have another constraint: the `Foo()` header cannot be modified :(

Answer (score 4):

Casting a reference into an unrelated reference type is not safe. While the cast itself has no side-effects, accessing the original object through the reference of another type has undefined behaviour (unless type aliasing rules provide an exception, like they do in the case of `char` but that does not apply here since standard specifies no such exception for `wxPoint`).

The conversion operator is not involved and makes no difference.

---

> An explanation of what is exactly going on when casting a reference in this way would be really appreciated.

The "C style" [cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) does one of const_cast, static_cast or reinterpret_cast or their combination, in that order of preference. There are no static_cast that apply to unrelated references.

Only thing that applies to converting `const Point&` into `wxPoint&` is reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast. [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) does:

> 6) An lvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type. No temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion functions are called. The resulting reference can only be accessed safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules (see below)

---

> The code shown here compiles without warnings.

Using reinterpret_cast is like telling the compiler that you know what you're doing might seem bonkers, but not to worry, you know what you're doing so no need to warn about it. Using it should be done with great care.

Since C style cast may do reinterpret_cast implicitly, the need for great care applies to it as well.